# How can an ambiguous grammar with quantifiers be transformed into LL1?

Tags: grammar, factorization, quantifiers

I cannot get my head around resolving this grammar (? means zero or one occurrences, + means at least one occurrence) into some equivalent that can be parsed using LL(1):

```
S -> X? Y+
X -> aU
Y -> aV
```

The problem is: when I see an 'a', was it produced by X or Y? Any ideas?

EDIT: U and V can start with the same symbol ...

Comment: Is `U` nullable? If so, the grammar is ambiguous. If not, it's not ambiguous but the grammar requires left-factoring to be LL.

Comment: You mean if U could be epsilon? No. Neither U nor V.

Comment: Then you need to left-factor

Comment: Yeah, but the quantifiers (?, +) are causing troubles then, aren't they?

Answer (score 1):

You need to left factor the rules, in order to create an LL(1) grammar. As long as `U` and `V` cannot start with the same symbol (and are not nullable), you could start with the equivalent regular expression  `a(Ua)?V(aV)*`.

If `U` and `V` can start with the same symbol, you'll also need to factor out the common prefix(es).

Comment: @simon, Then you'll need to do more left factoring. But the same model will work, probably.